# Cocos2d-x / cocos2d-js: How to set the --sign-identity option when making an ios release version

Tags: xcode, certificate, cocos2d-x, provisioning-profile, cocos2d-js

I try to run my app on an iPhone using cocos run -p ios -m release --sign-identity ...

I don't know what to state a sign identity parameter.

I created a development and a distribution certificate at the apple dev site.

[image]
Then I put the two certificates into the key chain:

[image]

Then I created two provisioning profiles in the ios Dev center (Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles) : one with wild card, one specific name

[image]

I download and imported it into Xcode (by doubleclicking on the file)

[image]

But still didn't figure out, what I have to write as parameter in the command line:

cocos run -p ios --sign-identity ???

Comment: Sounds like you are mistaking "certificate" for "provisioning profile", the latter is what you need to build and sign the app with. You need not know "where" your key pair is, Xcode will download the provisioning profile for you (Xcode: Window -> Organizer).

Comment: Thanks! Now I have a provisioning profile and I downloaded it into file "iOS_Team_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision". But the option --sign-identity doesn't take the file as a parameter. Same error message as before: "Code Sign error: No matching codesigning identity found: No codesigning identities (i.e. certificate and private key pairs) matching “../certs/iOS_Team_Provisioning_Profile_.mobileprovision” were found.". I don't find a command line example of it, where I could get a clou ...

Comment: did you read and follow the instructions on itunes connect?

Comment: I updated the question above. As you can see there I followed all the instructions in itunes connect and have signing keys and provisioning profiles and my IPhone has them connected to it. I just don't know how to tell all that to cocos ...

Comment: You don't "tell it to cocos2d". In the Build Settings for the app you can set the Code Signing profile. By default it should be set to automatic, meaning Xcode will manage the provisioning profiles for you. There should be no need to manually set the provisioning profiles. You also don't need to go to Terminal to sign the app, Xcode does that for you when you do a Product -> Archive build (a valid device must be selected, you can't do Archive builds for simulator). The result of an archive build is a file that Xcode can upload to Apple (in the window that pops up after the build).

Comment: I found it: It's just --sign-identity "iPhone Developer: Michael Schmidt" as cocos run option. That's what I meant when I said "tell it to cocos". Thanks anyway ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cocos command needs the option:

```
--sign-identity "iPhone Developer: [name]"
```

In my case:

```
--sign-identity "iPhone Developer: Michael Schmidt"
```

That's the name of the certificate in the key chain. See image 2 above.

After that you can add the .ipa-file in XCode: Window/Organizer Devices -- select a device -- Applications -- Add

The App is added to the device and can be started there.